# Arduino 1 can somehow support 32-bit audio?

Tags: arduino-uno

I wanted to take the audio from a device such as the PC, insert it through different ADC in arduino, processing them with DSP and DAC REnter all through to the other speakers, reading here and there on the internet but some people were put in difficulty because Arduino has a data bus to 10 bits. What problems can cause this? I can not send the same 10 bits at a time, until you arrive at 32?

Comment: 32 bit is high end audio electronics, don't expect to breadboard that with an Arduino at your desk at home. 16 bits is already a serious challenge, even in a professinal setting.

Comment: A processor can handle larger numbers one bit or word at a time, though you will soon hit the limit of the number of useful operations per second.  32 bits for a single audio channel is wasteful; limits of physics mean no circuit can be built without a noise level that would make many of them meaningless

Answer (score 1):

First of all,*what is the point of this?* [I'm afraid this is a XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You won't get that good of quality with Arduino. If you're hoping to create some sort of an amp, learn electronics and do that directly. Maybe you should just send data via serial.

Anyway, that aside, here's a chart I drew:

[image]
(Excuse my poor image alignment, PowerPoint was being a little mean today)

The bottom is all the "channels" the PC can send. The top is all the "channels" the Arduino can recieve. As you can see, there's a *huge* degradation in quality. Not to mention, I made this that 1 bit = 1 "channel," yet it's very much more than that.

A standard Arduino (Uno, Leonardo, etc.) has a 10 bit ADC that can read values 0-1023. The computer can output 0-4294967295! (It' exponentially grows due to permutations). You can see why I very much simplified my chart! :P

DSP won't really work well, unless you are trying to do some weird alien sounding modifications or a cheesy echo to. You probably will want to add an external 32 bit ADC. I would recommend, additionally, adding a Due or Galileo that can process 32 bit integers without emulating a bigger chip, thus greatly reducing performance and giving you a low framerate.

tl;dr: It'll work fine, but it'll have horrible sound quality. You can't send the same 10 bits until 32, since the computer changes that 32 bits into a voltage (sent to Arduino), and the Arduino translates that voltage into 10 bits.

Comment: The tl;dr is right on.  It's not a 10 bit data bus, it's a 10 bit ADC, so the additional bits go 'missing'  before your code ever sees them.  On the other hand, 10bit music might sound 4 times better than most [chiptunes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiptune) :)

Comment: @AShelly I'm pretty used to Bose products when I listen to music, so it sounds horrible IMHO :-)

Comment: thanks for your reply 
I was talking to put an external buffer which "splits" the 32 bits into four groups of 10 and a buffer at the end that joins the 4 groups. 
Or as you say, a 32-bit adc from outside, if I used it, arduino still could handle the computing power required to keep 4/5 digital filters together without any problems?

Comment: @Mario It really depends on what you're doing with the audio and how often you want to sample. If you don't mind sampling three times a second with external ADC and write directly after, you'll be fine. If you want to have 500 frames using a Uno and a 32 bit ADC and do complex computations, not so good. I'd recommend if you use a 32 bit ADC (not required, but significantly better quality), to use the Arduino Due since it has a 32 bit chip and a better architecture all around.

Comment: there is no such thing as a 32-bit adc!